# Find the probability of $\ A, B, C, D $

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose I have four events and I'll call them $\ A,B,C,D $ .

This is the information I'm given:

$$\ D \subseteq C \subseteq B \ \ ,P(A) = 0.59 , \ P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D) = 0.10 \\ P(A | D) = 0.50, \ P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) =0.8\\ P(A \cap B^c \cap C^c \cap D^c) = 0.2 \, \ \ P(A^c \cap B \cap C^c \cap D^c) = 0.1$$

$\ 1/3 $ of those that are part of three events ( $\ A, B,C,D $ ) do not belong to $\ D $ .

I need to find $\ P(A), P(B), P(C), P(D) $ . so far I got that because $\ D \subseteq C \subseteq B $ then $\ P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D) = P(A \cap D) = 0.10 \\ P(A | D) =  \frac{P(A\cap D)}{P(D)} = 0.10 \Rightarrow  P(D) = 0.2$

But couldn't find a way to find $\ P(B), P(C) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution:

Since $B^c\subseteq C^c\subseteq D^c$ we have:

$$P(A \cap B^c \cap C^c \cap D^c) = 0.2\implies P(A\cap B^c)=0.2$$
so $$\boxed{P(A)-P(A\cap B)=0.2}$$
and since $B\cup C\cup D=B$ we have $$P(A\cup B) =0.8$$

so $$\boxed{P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=0.8}$$

so we get $P(B)=0.6$

---

From here $$ P(A^c \cap B \cap C^c)  = 0.1$$ we should somehow find $P(C)$...

Comment: Could you just expalin why $\ P(A \cup B) = 0.8 $ that is not clear to me?

Comment: I made an edit...